# automatically route print jobs to different printer based on filename / job name

Tags: printing

What would be a good method to automatically route print jobs to different printers based on the printed filename?

It looks like [Ricoh Print and Share](http://www.printandshare.info/overview) may be able to do it though I haven't tried... they categorize the tool as a "virtual printer driver", but, in general it seems that we would just want to insert some program between the system print interface and the actual printer.  So, the term 'print filter' seems like it might be relevant also.

Thoughts?

UPDATE: RedMon looks interesting.  See [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400208)

Comment: Is this a programming question?  As written it looks like a question for SuperUser.com - https://superuser.com/ or ServerFault - https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I spose you could argue for or against any of those.  There are similar questions posted here, and similar questions posted there.