# Can't add new Redirected Port in Windows 7 after installing RedMon

Tags: windows-7, postscript, ghostscript, printers, redmon

My operating system is Windows 7 32bit. I installed **RedMon1.7**, **Ghostscript 8.71** and **GSview 4.9**; installations were successful.
I went to **Add New Local Printer** in Windows **Devices and Printers**, clicked on **Create A New Port**, and selected **Redirected Port** from the **Type of Port** list. Clicked Next and in the **Add New Port** window I named RPT1: and clicked OK but it says *Specified port cannot be added. Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000001)*

I tried giving different names to the port, RPT2:, RPT4:, VPport: etc but all gave same result. Disabled Windows Firewall and tried but it continues to give same error, Disabled the Antivirus (Avira) but no change.

What can be preventing windows 7 from adding redirected port?

BTW I was following instructions in this tutorial in order to create a postscript printer.

http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSPSprinter/GSPSprinter.html

Appreciate any ideas or suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run cmd.exe as Administrator and then run:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /il
```

from the elevated cmd.

Comment: Please explain, albeit briefly, your solution.

Comment: " /il - Installs a printer by using the Add Printer wizard ". Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: To edit existing printer use 
*rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n   "printer name" /p*

Comment: Although this works, they have released a new version of RedMon more compatible with Windows 7 and up, and in the "Common problems" section of the help they describe how to manage printers with full administrative rights using the Print Management applet of the Administrative Tools (this allow not only adding the port but also change its settings and deleting it).

Answer (score 5):

Go to your Start Menu,
Type Print,
Right-Click "Print Management",
Select "Run as administrator",

In Print Management; Expand "Print Servers" and Select "Ports".

Right-Click in the "Ports" pane (on the right hand side) and Select "Add Port...".

I'd also recommend configuring a Port from Print Management, as opposed to trying to do it in a Printers Properties. ;)

Comment: Worked for me. I think, I did not even need to run it as admin.

Answer (score 3):

Adam Reed describes a workaround in his blog:
http://borntoidentify.blogspot.com/2010/09/configuring-virtual-printer-using.html
Not very comfortable, but works for me ...

EDIT: This link appears broken, but here's the content:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120628120209/http://borntoidentify.blogspot.com/2010/09/configuring-virtual-printer-using.html

The gist is that under Win7, you need to run explorer with elevated rights. This can be done using another browser, or, as mentioned in the comments on the original post:

1. Open a CMD window by right clicking and running as administrator
2. Kill the process explorer.exe from the task manager
3. Run explorer.exe from the command prompt window, now as an administrator.

Be very careful when running explorer as an administrator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and resources.

Comment: Best option until RedMon add support for Vista/7. Note that you don't a command line program, you can use any program that can launch another program (I used Total Commander instead of XTerm). I think that an elevated cmd.exe would work too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Admin mode OR log with the Admin account!

This is cause by the new Vista/Win 7 security system.

Comment: how to enable admin mode exactly? already logged in with an administrator account. Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: Hi Zerone, have you figured out how to enable admin mode?

Comment: No I have not yet. What about you?

Answer (score 1):

Try reseting the firewall (Windows 7)
(be warned tho, the firewall will reset to the default setting)
*go to Control Panel
*go to Windows Firewall
*on the left choice pick "Restore Defaults"

It works for me, i hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

F3lix's rundll32 method works but after you've created the port you most probably would need to configure its settings. Elsewhere in the net there are instructions to open Port management as Administrator, but in Windows 7 Home that seems to be very much impossible. One can only view the virtual port settings. The only workaround I found is to edit registry directly with the Registry editor at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Redirected Port\Ports\RPT1:
```

(Replace your port name in the end.)

Answer (score 1):

It seams to be tricky. In my case it only works, after creating an new User account with the name "admin" / group " Administratoren" (de).
Before with my real Nickname User "Nick.." / group "Administratoren" (de) it dosent work´.
Takes several hours to discover ...

Answer (score 1):

Accepted solution did not work for me...I found an other command line that worked well (I'm on windows 10):

```
%systemroot%\system32\printmanagement.msc
```

It opens the print management in administrator mode, and I was able to create the port with no problems.

Comment: were you able to run redmon on windows 10? I was able to add port, but not able to assign printer to this port.

Comment: I installed Redmon on Windows 10. When I created the port and asking my printer to it, I was able to start a small application I made in reaction. But I quickly found that it was very complicated to access the data, and I stopped working on that part...